# Calculate total average in listbox from another listbox

Tags: c#, algorithm, listbox

I have these values in my listbox (above the left listbox you see the headers of the table, but this is in Dutch):
[image]

In the `listbox` on the right you see: `employeeid`, `questionid` and `score`. In the `listbox` on the right I want the `total average score` of every `employeeid`, by a press on a `button`. I need to make a `algorithm`, that takes the correct values of the `listbox`.
How can I do this? I don't know how I can say that I only want certain values from the `listbox` (`employeeid` and `score`, and not `questionid`).

I'm using a `class` to load in the data:

```
public List<ScoreMdw> GetScoreMdwList()
        {
            List<ScoreMdw> scoremdwList = new List<ScoreMdw>();
            conn.Open();
            string query = ("Select employeeid, questionid, score from contentment");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

        try
        {
            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    ScoreMdw sm = new ScoreMdw((int)dr["employeeid"], (int)dr["questionid"], (int)dr["score"]);
                    scoremdwList.Add(sm);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Exception error = new Exception("error", ex);
            throw error;
        }

        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

        return scoremdwList;
    }
```

In the while loop I'm using an other `class`:

```
class ScoreMdw
    {
        private int employeeid;
        private int questionid;
        private int score;
    public ScoreMdw(int nr, int id, int s)
    {
        this.employeeid= nr;
        this.questionid= id;
        this.score = s;
    }

    public int EmployeeId
    {
        get { return employeeid; }
    }

    public int QuestionId
    {
        get { return questionid; }
    }

    public int Score
    {
        get { return score; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string s = string.Format("{0} \t{1} \t{2}", this.employeeid, this.questionid, this.score);
        return s;
    }
}
```

In my `main window` I'm doing this:

```
private void btnLoadScores_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            scoremdwList = new List<ScoreMdw>();

        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            List<string> headers = so.GetContentmentHeaders();

            foreach (string header in headers)
                txtHeader.Text += header + "\t";

            scoremdwList = so.GetScoreMdwList();
            lbScores.ItemsSource = scoremdwList;
        }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: More code is needed! Post the code you have tried to calculate it, or at least the event handler for the button click and the code that fills the other listbox.

Comment: Rather than setting yourself up to have to parse a string, you could use *data binding* to display a `List<T>` in the list box and get back the properties you want

Comment: @JLe Just added my code.

Answer (score 1):

You need a linq query to sum up score of same employee id like

```
lbScores.ItemsSource = (from e in scoremdwList
    group e by e.EmployeeId into grp
    select new 
    {
        EmployeeId = grp.Key,
        TotalScore = grp.Sum(a => a.Score)
    }).ToList();
```

Where EmployeeId and TotalScore are the columns of target listbox

Comment: I don't want to do it with query's etc. Just with a good algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

```
        // string: employeeid - first int: total score - second int: number of questions
        Dictionary<string, Tuple<int, int>> results = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<int, int>>();
        foreach (ListViewItem item in lstvwSource.Items)
        {
            // check if employeeid is in Dictionary
            if (results.ContainsKey(item.Text))
            {
                // if employeeid exists in dictionary
                // add currnet score to total score
                // and add one to number of questions
                results[item.Text] = new Tuple<int, int>(Convert.ToInt32(item.SubItems[1].Text) + results[item.Text].Item1, +results[item.Text].Item2 + 1);
            }
            else
            {
                // if employeeid does not exist in dictionary
                // add employeeid , score of the question
                // set number of questions to 1
                Tuple<int, int> tuple = new Tuple<int, int>(Convert.ToInt32(item.SubItems[1].Text), 1);
                results.Add(item.Text, tuple);
            }
        }
        // 
        lstvwDest.Items.Clear();
        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            ListViewItem newItem = new ListViewItem();
            newItem.Text = result.Key; // employeeid
            newItem.SubItems.Add(result.Value.Item1.ToString()); // total score
            double avg = (double)result.Value.Item1 / (double)result.Value.Item2;
            newItem.SubItems.Add(avg.ToString()); // average score
            lstvwDest.Items.Add(newItem);
        }
```

Comment: Is this the total average score per employee? Can you comment on your code? Thanks

Comment: Yes .it is total average score per employee. I will comment it later

Comment: I wait for you comments :)

Comment: I added comments.